# Error in pyspark word count: ValueError: empty separator

Tags: python, split, pyspark

Here is the s84.txt which is on hdfs and I want to do wordcount on it:

> [paslechoix@gw03 ~]$ hdfs dfs -cat s84.txt 
>   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
>   text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been
>   the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
>
> when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make
>   a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
>   also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>
> remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
>   the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
>   more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
>
> PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

```
s84RDD = sc.textFile("p84.txt") 
nonempty_lines = s84RDD.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0)
words = nonempty_lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split("")) 
wc = words.map(lambda x: (x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y).map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])).sortByKey(False)
```

Error:

ValueError: empty separator

What am I missing here? Thank you very much.

Comment: What are you trying to `split()` on? An empty string is not a valid argument, no argument defaults to whitespace, any explicit argument is used for the split. Note: your test for an empty line may not be correct. BTW you show `s84.txt` but are loading `p84.txt`.

Comment: Thank you AChampion for noticing the missing space and the confusing file name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

`split()` needs a separator. You are using `split("")` with argument as `""` which is an empty string.

```
>>> '1,2,3'.split(',')
['1', '2', '3']

>>> '1 2 3'.split()
['1', '2', '3']

>>> "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet".split("")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    x.split("")
ValueError: empty separator

>>> "Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet".split(" ")
['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'sit', 'dolor', 'amet']
```